# How to Combine Backbone with Meteor

Tags: backbone.js, meteor

I'm currently working on a complex single page web app. It's something like a charting program: you can select or add objects on a white page. There's many types of objects. If you select some of type A objects, then it will add/remove B/C/D objects based on a complex logic.  I'm currently using Backbone.Model for these objects. And Backbone.View for displaying. It's a pretty standard MVC structure, with models for objects data, controllers for managing models and views, and views for displaying. It's all using DOM elements. The views are added, removed or updated (with CSS) based on model data.

It works great and now I'm trying to add server side to save and load all data to/from the server. I planned to write a REST API server with restify for all the models.

Then I find meteor.js, the 'realtime', 'reactivity' and 'database everywhere' features intrigue me. So it will greatly simplify my app if I can save and load my models directly and let meteor to do the sync. And the real time feature can be a great plus for my future features, such as adding realtime collaboration.

But it seems meteor has a very different idea from Backbone on how a web app is structured. How can I combine meteor with my current Backbone code? Do you have any great suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, don't. Do meteor all the way, or do backbone, but meteor is pretty much a combined full-stack solution not really intended for use with something like backbone. Meteor already provides deeply-integrated components that address all the areas that backbone addresses (data sync, DOM updates, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm thinking about transporting from Backbone to Meteor. But meteor does not have a model system. It's really easy to bind UI to data records in database. But I need complex logic and model relationships. How can I do that? I'm new to meteor, and still can't bind my mind to the way it works. :)